# Span of Nilpotent Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Can any matrix be represented as a finite sum of nilpotent matrices?

Of course, if the diagonal is filled with zeros it is possible. What about $I_n$, the identity matrix, for example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Nilpotent matrices have zero trace, and thus any linear combination of nilpotent matrices has zero trace.